# using assembly.load with a specific file location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, .net-assembly

I have the current file structure in my Visual Studio project:

- MyProject/

  - MyStartupProject/

    - bin/

      - Debug/
    - Program.cs
  - DependencyProject/

    - bin/
    - dlls/

      - MyAssembly.dll
    - Code.cs

My `Main()` function is inside `MyProject/MyStartupProject/Program.cs`. Inside `Code.cs` is a line `var assembly = Assembly.Load("MyAssembly");`, which is supposed to load `MyProject/DependencyProject/dlls/MyAssembly.dll`, but instead it causes the error

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

However, everything runs perfectly fine if I copy `MyAssembly.dll` into `MyProject/MyStartupProject/bin/Debug`. How do I fix this reference so the project can find it under the dlls directory?

Comment: you need to add it as a project resource, then it'll get copied across the profiles

Comment: how do I add it as a project resource? @Jazb

Comment: The build system doesn't know that you have a dependency on this DLL, so won't copy it for you.  You [have to help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21760295/17034).  Or use LoadFrom() instead of Load().  Or just use a project reference and use types from the assembly in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by adding the following to my `DependencyProject.csproj`

```
<ContentWithTargetPath Include="dlls\MyAssembly.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <TargetPath>MyAssembly.dll</TargetPath>
</ContentWithTargetPath>
```

This causes the dlls to be automatically copied into `MyStartupProject/bin/Debug/`.

Answer (score 0):

### Try to Change the status of `MyAssembly.dll` to `Copy if new`.

[image]

### Update:

[image]

#### Add file

[image]

[image]

### Update2:Is there a way I can get it to copy straight into Debug/ without moving the original out of the dlls/ directory?

Two solutions:

1. Change `var assembly = Assembly.Load("MyAssembly");` to `var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("dlls\MyAssembly.dll");`.
2. [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2022#example-1)

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <Copy
            SourceFiles="dlls\MyAssembly.dll"
            DestinationFolder="bin\Debug"
        />
    </Target>
```

to `csproj`.

##### csproj:

1. Unload Project:

[image]

2.Double-click Project:

[image]

Comment: I have a "Copy Local" which is already set to true, but no "Copy to Output Directory" option. I am using .NET Framework if that makes a difference

Comment: Please check my updates, did you right-click on this property? I am .Net Framework 4.8.

Comment: I found that the assembly was copied to `MyStartupProject/bin/Debug/dlls/MyAssembly.dll`, rather than `MyStartupProject/bin/Debug/MyAssembly.dll` and the error persists. Is there a way I can get it to copy straight into `Debug/` without moving the original out of the `dlls/` directory?

Comment: Please check my updates, If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: I found another way to resolve my error so I did not get a chance to try your update

Comment: @wheeeee If you try to check my update you will find your answer in my latest update.