# How to include third party exe in visual studio 2010 setup and deployment project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exe, setup-project

Let's say `A.exe` is the my `exe` project which runs fine at `windows system`.

Let's say `B.exe` is the external third party driver which is required for `A.exe`. Currently I am installing both projects separately. Now, I want to include the driver into my `A.exe`installation, s that when the user installs `A.exe`, `B.exe` automatically gets installed first.

How should I do that?

Comment: try to add it to Resources.

Comment: Where is it ? I clicked on setup project but didn't find anything looks like "Add resource"

Comment: not inside the setup wizard, add it as project resource - in the solution explorer, just like you add images and other media files.

Comment: I do right click on solution and it is showing `"Add existing item", "Add new item", "Add new project", "Add existing project"`. BTW i added a new folder and put `exe` and it's dependecies in it. Now when i choose project output in `setup project`, I am not able to choose that folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596508/vs2010-how-to-include-files-in-project-to-copy-them-to-build-output-directory-a

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

1. From the Project menu, select Add and click File.
2. Find the folder that contains MyApplication.exe and MyLibrary.DLL and select them both.
3. In the File System window, right-click on Application Folder, point to Add and click Create to create a new folder. Call it MyLibrary.
4. Click on Application Folder again, select MyLibrary.DLL and drag it to the MyLibrary folder.In Solution Explorer, under your project in Detect Dependencies you should see that the Visual Studio detects dependencies on MFC90.dll and MSVCR90.dll. You must add the corresponding Merge Modules for these DLLs.
5. From the Project menu, point to Add and click Merge Module. Select Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86.msm and Microsoft_VC90_MFC_x86.msm, and click OK. For the debug versions of these merge modules, select Microsoft_VC90_DebugCRT_x86.msm and Microsoft_VC90_DebugMFC_x86.msm.

For VS2010 deployent examples take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235285%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).