# How to copy .exe from output directory on project/solution build automatically in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build

So looking at this post, [VS2010 How to include files in project, to copy them to build output directory automatically during build or publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596508/).

This seems to be pretty close to what I am looking to do, however what I want is to have the .exe that is built be copied to a second output directory.

To help explain, when I build/rebuild my project/solution the .exe's are put in

`[somepath]\Projects\[NameOfSolution]\[NameOfProject]\bin\Release\outputFile.exe`

What I would like to do is have visual studio automatically make a copy of that `outputFile.exe` to some other directory, like say a server share on the network that I have read/write access to. The catch is that server share is not always available since I write my code on a traveling laptop. So need to have some sort of logic to check for that I guess...

I truly don't even know where to begin; if it's even possible to do it in Visual Studio. I tried looking into post-build actions in my project settings, but I have no idea what to do in the dialog box. I tried Googling how to do it, but since I don't even know how to explain what I want very well, the google results were useless.

Comment: PostBuild actions are the right path to solve your problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy file(s) from one project to another using post build event...VS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001822/copy-files-from-one-project-to-another-using-post-build-event-vs2010)

Comment: @onskee  You are correct. Like I said, I didn't know how to explain what I wanted, so when I searched I didn't find relevant results.

Comment: That's okay.  Just trying to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact a duplicate of [Copy file(s) from one project to another using post build event...VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001822)

Like I said, I didn't know how to explain what I wanted, so when I searched I didn't find relevant results.

In case anyone comes to this question via a google search in the future, the following Post-Build Event command worked for me (has to all be on one line):

`if $(ConfigurationName) == Release copy /B /Y /V "$(TargetPath)" "\\some\path\to\file\share\$(TargetFileName)"`