# How to publish and use an Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I wrote a program in WPF that has to write in an Excel file. The Excel File already exists (I created it so the file exists!), but I want that if I publish my program that users also have this Excel file 
automatically.

So how can I fill this gap with the "?" (There should be the Excel file)

At the moment, I only open the file:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.AlsExcel == true)
{
    Excel.Application objExcel = new Excel.Application();
    objExcel.Visible = false;
    objExcel.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlNormal;

    object missing = Missing.Value;
    string Name = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "DienstplanEx.xlsx");
    Excel.Workbook objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Name, missing, missing, missing,
        missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
        missing, missing);
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)objWorkbook.Worksheets["Tabelle1"];
    if (!Directory.Exists(Pfad))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Pfad);
    }
    objWorkbook.SaveAs(Pfad + "\\Plan.xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    objWorkbook.Close();
    objExcel.Quit();
```

Comment: It's not really easy to understand your question. Can you rephrase it, please?

Comment: Im sorry, my English is very bad :D

Comment: Edited! @Alex Butenko

Comment: Can you provide more details? What kind of application? (Web, Desktop, Forms. WPF, MVC etc.). Also, do you create an Excel file from scratch, write to it and save or you want to open an existing template, write to it and save?

Comment: You may want to see if `Excel.Application`, `Excel.Workbook`, `Excel.Worksheet` are `IDisposable` so that handles aren't kept open accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking only how to include a file to the program you are distributing.

What you have to do is include the Excel file into your project and set the *Build Action* to *Content* in *Properties* window for that file. 
If you have an installer project, this file should then get included into your installation (if not, you should add *Content Files* as a Project Output on your installer).

Check [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(v=vs.90).aspx) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596508/vs2010-how-to-include-files-in-project-to-copy-them-to-build-output-directory-a) resources for more help.

Comment: Exactly! Sorry for my bad English :/

Comment: And How can I use this file? I need a path to this file...!?

Comment: I'm not sure what your scenario is but 
- you could host your file just next to the executable and access it with ```Path.Combine``` and ```AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory``` or perhaps ```System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location``` and handle the relative path from there
- or if you'd install the file to user's ```%AppData%``` folder, then you can get it with ```Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)``` - see also [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-sharp-getting-the-path-of-appdata)