# Why my code can not find the path in project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, itext

I am using this to merge 2 pad files:

```
public static void MergePages(string outputPdfPath, string[] lstFiles)
{
    lstFiles = new string[2] { @"Downloads\Certificates\119.FDV-3686.pdf", 
                               @"Downloads\Certificates\119.FDV-3686.pdf" };
    outputPdfPath = @"Downloads\Certificates\";

    PdfReader reader = null;
    Document sourceDocument = null;
    PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
    PdfImportedPage importedPage;
    sourceDocument = new Document(); 
    pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument,
    new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
    sourceDocument.Open();
    try
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < lstFiles.Length - 1; f++)
        {
            int pages = 1;
            reader = new PdfReader(lstFiles[f]);
            //Add pages of current file
            for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
            {
                importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        sourceDocument.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The 2 files exists in my project directory but it throws error:

**Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\Downloads\Certificates\119.FDV-3686.pdf'.**

I don't understand why it goes to `C` drive since files are in the same project.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

(1) One problem might be that your design-time pdf files are not copied to application output directory during compilation. Therefore they are not available run-time.

If you want to copy file(s) from your solution folder to application output directory, you can set to file property "*Copy to Output directory*" to "*Copy always*" or "*Copy if newer*". More discussion about topic is found i.e [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596508/vs2010-how-to-include-files-in-project-to-copy-them-to-build-output-directory-a).

File properties can be set by selecting file under solution explorer.

(2) Another problem is that you do not set root directory of file path. I recommend you to express file path with following style:

```
var rootLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase.ToString()).LocalPath);
var filePath1  = Path.Combine(rootLocation,@"Downloads\Certificates\filename1.pdf"); 
var filePath2  = Path.Combine(rootLocation,@"Downloads\Certificates\filename2.pdf"); 
..
```

Comment: it is target the temporary asp.net files

Comment: @CodingManiac I changed my answer, check out rootLocation resolving now..