# How to get an array from appsettings.json file in .Net 6?

Tags: arrays, json, console-application, .net-6.0

I've read this excellent SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65110479/how-to-get-values-from-appsettings-json-in-a-console-application-using-net-core) on how to get access to the `appsettings.json` file in a .Net 6 console app.

However, in my json file I have several arrays:

```
"logFilePaths": [
    "\\\\server1\\c$\\folderA\\Logs\\file1.log",
    "\\\\server2\\c$\\folderZ\\Logs\\file1A1.log",
    "\\\\server3\\c$\\folderY\\Logs\\file122.log",
    "\\\\server4\\c$\\folderABC\\Logs\\fileAB67.log"
  ],
```

And I get the results if I do something like this:

```
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true);
    var config = builder.Build();

    string logFile1 = config["logFilePaths:0"];
    string logFile2 = config["logFilePaths:1"];
    string logFile3 = config["logFilePaths:2"];
```

But I don't want to have to code what is effectively an array into separate lines of code, as shown.

I want to do this:

```
string[] logFiles = config["logFilePaths"].Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

But it gives me an error on `config["logFilePaths"]` saying it's `null`.

Why would that be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the `logFilePaths` as an array, you want to use the [Get<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-configuration-configurationbinder-get-1(microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfiguration)) extension method:

```
string[] logFilePaths = config.GetSection("logFilePaths").Get<string[]>();
```

Comment: CS1061 'IConfigurationSection' does not contain a definition for 'Get' and no accessible extension method 'Get' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: @Fandango68 install `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to install `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` nuget and use `Bind` (do not forget to setup `CopyToOutputDirectory` for `appsettings.json`):

```cs
var list = new List<string>();
config.Bind("logFilePaths", list);
```

Another - via `GetSection` (using the same nuget to bind a collection):

```cs
var list = config.GetSection("logFilePaths").Get<List<string>>();
```