# TeamCity doesn't copy all referenced libraries

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, build, teamcity

I have a solution with a web application, from within the webapp I'm referencing another project that references and external library.

```
WebApp -> SupportingProject -> ExternalDll
```

everything is fine when I build the solution in debug/release inside visual studio, but when it gets built in TeamCity one of the references doesn't get copied over. all other files referenced by the supporting project are copied except that single one.

I was able to get around this by directly adding a reference to that library, but wanted to figure out the underlying cause of it.

all the references are marked as copy local.

I'm using the Visual Studio (sln) build runner in teamcity.

Comment: If you open the .csproj in notepad, what do you see in Project References section. For example, the Include attribute below should resolve to a path that team city can recognize, i.e. by using relative paths <ProjectReference Include="..\Test.SampleClient\Test.SampleClient.ConsoleApp.csproj">
      <Project>{766C00FD-C19E-4A15-BA7E-FB4BB2385732}</Project>
      <Name>ExternalReference.dll</Name>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an issue with TeamCity but the way that VisualStudio and MSBuild work and what you are doing is correct. See SO Question [MSBuild doesn't copy references (DLL files) if using project dependencies in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dlls-if-using-project-dependencies-in-solution)