# Referenced DLL not copied to Output directory

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have 2 projects in my solution: project A and B. I added a dll reference to my project A. Now when i build the project A the dll is copied to the project A output directory. Now if i reference project to project A from project B, the dll is newer copied to projects B output folder. Why is that?

Is this by design from Microsoft?

Comment: Don't you need to add the DLL reference to Project B also?

Comment: Maybe thats the question, do i?

Comment: did you set `Copy Local` in reference properties to `True`?

Comment: @hs2d. This is how Visual Studio compiles projects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dlls-if-using-project-dependencies-in-solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose wether the assemblies are copied by setting the "copy to output" option.

In my projects the once which produce a runtime (Console,App, unit tests)..), are copying refs to local.
This is important because without that the app wouldn't run.

The other projects (components and so on) are bulding to a central binary folder and are not copying their references, becuase they were taken from there.
This saves a huge amount of build time.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this by design from Microsoft?

Yes.