# Referenced project dependencies DLL are not being copied

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2017, dependencies, .net-assembly

My project solution is currently having three projects:

1. **MyProject**, which is my main startup project (using `.NET Framework 4.7`) - WPF, UI specfic,
2. **MyProject.Core** - class library (`.NET Standard 2.0`) - holding the models, and all of the 'behind the scenes' data
3. **MyProject.Relational** - class library (`.NET Standard 2.0`) - responsible for processing and saving the database specific informations

Project `1` (main) has set a reference to project `2` and `3`.

For the project `3` I have installed a `NuGet` dependency of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite (2.0.3)`.

Now, when I finally want to make use of project `3` and call it's method, the following exception is being thrown:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This, of course is a missing DLL file - no entity framework DLL's are being copied to the app `Debug` directory.

**Why is that**? Is this intended behaviour? Do I have to install the dependency of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` for project `1` as well? Pretty pointless to me, referencing the same dependency to project that is making no use of it.

**What have I tried:**

- Cleaning up the project, removing bin/obj directories,
- Set project reference properties setting `copy local` to `True`,
- Solutions given in this question: [Referenced DLL not being copied to referencing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133109/referenced-dll-not-being-copied-to-referencing-project)

Using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore in your project references?

Comment: Btw i just tried this nuget and it works for me, maybe update your nugets, or do a update-package -reinstall on your project

Comment: @TheGeneral Yes it is https://i.imgur.com/h8Bhfnd.png. It is referenced in project `3`. `update-package -reinstall` did not help. The problem is that those DLL files are not being copied into my app directory.

Comment: can you send an image of your CSPROJ file for MyProject.Relational?

Comment: Hmm, very insteresting. I have looked into CSPROJ file and added following line `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>` to the `PropertyGroup` and now everything works like a charm... (I found the line in my old project's CSPROJ file). I have no idea why this line wasn't added into my CSPROJ automatically... If someone could explain this and post an answer, that would be great!

Comment: @DonaldDuck: I'd recommend you add that as an answer, for the poor person that comes across your question ;)

Comment: @DonaldDuck, I knew it was CSPROJ :)

Comment: @joey Yeah, you gave me an idea :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved this by adding the following line into my `.csproj` file:

```
<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
```

Specifically to the `PropertyGroup` group.

Not sure why it makes such difference, if anyone could explain and post in the comment it would be great. Any additional informations I will add to this answer.

Comment: Thanks for this, as it pointed me in the right direction. A more detailed explanation is here: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx

Comment: After using this magic fix I had to install package again as nuget tool forget it installed.

Comment: This needs a thousand upvotes.  You must get rid of packages.config files.  Migrate .NET Standard libraries from packages.config to PackageReference.  I then had to add <RuntimeIdentifier>win</RuntimeIdentifier> in main project to make NuGet work correctly.