# ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll no longer copied over to dependent projects

Tags: servicestack

After upgrading to ServiceStack v3.9.70 via nuGet from v3.9.43, I noticed that the `ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll` is no longer copied over to projects that depend on the class library using ServiceStack. This causes the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

All other ServiceStack dlls are copied, only ServiceStack.Interfaces is missing. All references are set to `Copy Local = True`, and this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dlls-if-using-project-dependencies-in-solution)'s suggestion does not solve the problem.

I noticed that `ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll` is the only one with a version of *1.0.0.0*, all others are set to *3.9.70.0*. Could this be a cause?

Does anyone know how to fix it without manually referencing ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll in cascade in all projects referencing my class library?

## Update - 2014-03-06

Problem still exists with v3.9.71.0. It really is related to the fact that the `ServiceStack.Interfaces` assembly has its version left to 1.0.0.0 instead of being.

I cloned the github repository for ServiceStack and changed this line in the `build\build.proj` file and ran `build\build.bat`.

```
<!-- Exclude versioning future strong-named libs -->
<RegexTransform Include="$(BuildSolutionDir)/src/**/AssemblyInfo.cs"
                Exclude="$(SrcDir)/ServiceStack.Interfaces*/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs">
   <Find>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+</Find>
   <ReplaceWith>$(Version)</ReplaceWith>
</RegexTransform>
```

for this (noticed the removed exclusion)

```
<RegexTransform Include="$(BuildSolutionDir)/src/**/AssemblyInfo.cs">
   <Find>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+</Find>
   <ReplaceWith>$(Version)</ReplaceWith>
</RegexTransform>
```

**Result**: Now it works correctly, i.e. the file `ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll` is copied over to projects referencing a project that references `ServiceStack`.

Can someone explains this to me? Why would you want to exclude the Interfaces from versionning?

Comment: Any success on this meanwhile?

Comment: Sadly, apart from manually adding references, no.

Answer (score 1):

The assembly versions were intentionally changed from 3.9.* to 1.0.0.0 when the v4 was released.

It probably was due to [v4 ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll being changed to being strong-named and versioned 4.0](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#wiki-servicestackinterfaces-is-now-strong-named). The 'bsd' 3.9.* version was rolled back to 1.0, probably to be clearly the oldest possible.

More detail in noted in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283965/is-there-a-build-issue-in-the-recent-versions-of-servicestack-3).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know how to fix the DLL copying problem without changing the version number back up to 3.9 then?

Comment: It may also be necessary to add a reference to something in ServiceStack.Interaces; see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26163368/210780