# Is there a build issue in the recent versions of ServiceStack 3?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I have had the following warning show up in visual studio when compiling a project using ServiceStack 3.9.71.0 (seems to affect most recent releases too).  Not sure why it hasn't shown up before but it has started showing up after I created a test lib which references my main project and both have references to the same service stack DLLs:

> Warning   2   Found conflicts between different versions of the same
>   dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference
>   conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to
>   detailed. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    1635

Inspecting the build log shows:

> 10>  There was a conflict between "ServiceStack.Interfaces,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and
>   "ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=3.9.60.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null". 10>      "ServiceStack.Interfaces,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" was chosen
>   because it was primary and "ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=3.9.60.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" was not. 10>      References
>   which depend on "ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
>   [C:\proj\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll] ...

This error is correct as it seems an older version of ServiceStack.Interfaces is referenced (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opary.png) by the latest releases in NuGet in addition to an old version of ORMLite.  I have removed all previous versions of ServiceStack from my system so its not picking up any old DLLs. My projects just have references to ServiceStack, common, interfaces and text; I removed ORM as I do not use it but adding it to both projects did not help.

A little unsure how I can resolve this error as Github does not seem to have been updated since 3.9.60, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a warning, it should build, and can safely be ignored. The error message does indicate that the build system correctly chose v1.0.0.0.

> "ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" was chosen

The version was intentionally reset from 3.9 to 1.0, about 4 months ago [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/f1e56982bf5259f09f755289678674e31299d51d). This coincides with the beta release of ServiceStack v4. Presumably the v3 assembly versions where reset to a low number to allow for future BSD builds to be created without encroaching on the v4 version numbering, and to denote the clear change of project ownership.

Comment: how can I supress it? Our CI process requires absence of warnings in the code. Please, advice