# MSBuild not copying all DLL references

Tags: c#, msbuild, ninject, lazy-loading, ninject-extensions

I have a C# .NET 4.5 solution like this:

```
Project A.dll
-> Third Party.dll

Project B.dll
-> Project A.dll
```

When I build `Project B`, `Third Party.dll` isn't copied to the `bin` folder. However, it works if I add a reference to `Third Party.dll` like:

```
Project B.dll
-> Project A.dll
-> Third Party.dll
```

It also works if I do something like this inside `Project B`:

```
var t = typeof(ThirdParty.SomeClass);
```

I don't remember having this issue in the past. Any ideas?

I'm using `Ninject v3.2` and `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions v3.2`. Is it possible that Ninject does dynamic assembly loading behind the scenes, and the compiler is running optimizations that strip out unused libraries?

Comment: Did you find out what it was caused by? It probably was soemthing with Project A's setup, wasn't it? like being built to another target folder?

Comment: This post should set you along the right path. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dlls-if-using-project-dependencies-in-solution?rq=1