# C# Assembly in VB Web App Solution

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, jenkins, .net-assembly

I have an assembly I wrote in C# and added as a project to a VB (Framework 4.5) Web App solution. All works well locally, but when Jenkins builds the sln, it never deploys my DLL to bin. Any ideas? My assembly is marked as a dependency and Copy Local is True.

When it builds in DEV (with Jenkins) and I go to the page that references it, I get this:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'TronixUIControls' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 3:  <%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="ajaxasp" %>
Line 4:  <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
Line 5:  <%@ Register Assembly="TronixUIControls" Namespace="CustomButtons" TagPrefix="btb" %>
Line 6:  
Line 7:  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="SubHeader" Runat="Server"> 

Source File: /Contract/ContractLookup.aspx    Line: 5 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'TronixUIControls' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
LOG: DisplayName = TronixUIControls
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: TronixUIControls | Domain ID: 3
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/TRONIX/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TRONIX\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TRONIX\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
```

Comment: Is your build configuration that you are using in jenkins setup to build that project?

Comment: Yes, when I push in GIT, Jenkins picks it up and builds it using the SLN file. Locally, no. Just a normal solution and it gets copied just fine, but Jenkins just does not deploy it.

Comment: The build SHOULD copy it to bin on the DEV site, but does not. At all!

Comment: If I manually drop it there, all is fine.

Comment: Have you read through this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132243/573218

Comment: Yes. I forced the private true and it did not help.

Comment: Did you check your framework versions on both projects?