# Assemblies/references not found after publication on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, reference, csproj

I have an MVC5 Web application (VS2012) which has a reference to a WCF Application.
The architecture looks like this:

```
- Business library
-- References to DAL
- DAL library
- WCF application
-- References to Ressources
-- References to Business
-- References to DAL
- Web application
-- References to WCF application
-- References to Ressources
- AzureCloudService
-- WebRole for Web application
-- WebRole for WCF application
- Ressources
-- References to Business
-- References to DAL
```

I have created a AzureCloudService with 2 WebRoles for Web and Wcf applications. When I publish the AzureCloudService, no errors are thrown.
But when I go to the Web application on Azure, many references or assemblies are not found. So, I had to add the following line in .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="Tools, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

Because the project reference was not enough:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Tools\Tools.csproj">
  <Project>{guid}</Project>
  <Name>Tools</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

But, when I added Wcf application and Ressources references, it asks for Business even if there is no project reference in Web Application. After all, I ended with the following error which makes me feel that I'm doing wrong. Has somebody a hint or advice please?

```
Couldn't find type for class Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
```

Of course, the following line is present in the .csproj but doesn't seem to work ... or I don't understand something.

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=somenumber">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
After some research, I've found out that all the project references in my WebRoles are not included while the Cloud Services publication.

- Firstly, I tried to set Copy Local to true (even if they already were).
- Secondly, I deleted my WebRoles and recreated them.
- Thirdly, I try to add some dummy code to reference the projects indirectly as suggested in this post: [MSBuild doesn't copy references (DLL files) if using project dependencies in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dlls-if-using-project-dependencies-in-solution)
- Then, I tried to add the project dependencies on the Cloud Service Project.
- Then, I tried to create a package, rename .cspkg in .zip, unzip it, add the missing dlls to the unzipped WebRole .cssx, and re deploy as suggested in this post: http://blog.toddysm.com/2010/02/windows-azure-deployment-did-you-forget-to-pack-your-dlls.html
- I know there are scripts for post build events, but I don't succeeded to create one.

For now, I have to access the Cloud Services VM via Remote Desktop and copy/paste the .dll from my local "/bin" directory to the approot and siteroot "/bin" directories.
However, when an instance is destroyed and recreated due to Azure scalability, the .dll are gone.
So, I'm desperate with these projects dll which are not sent.

Any ideas please?