# SignalR self host inside class library

Tags: wpf, signalr, class-library

I have application, which uses module with signalR hub and its self hosting.
Running method

```
 WebApp.Start(url);
```

calls next  exception

```
System.MissingMemberException: 'The server factory could not be located for the given input: Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener'
```

But when I installed signalR selfhost packages to my application too, it starts working fine, without any errors.
Can somebody pls explain me such strange behavior or possible ways to fix it without installing that packages to main project ?

Comment: The HttpListener isn't directly used in the project so its DLL is not copied to output in this case. I think there's a question about this here, I had the same issue a few days back. I'll try to look

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["System.MissingMemberException: The server factory could not be located" starting Microsoft.Owin self-hosted in TeamCity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050588/system-missingmemberexception-the-server-factory-could-not-be-located-startin)