# Resolving another project's renamed assembly dependency

Tags: msbuild

I have a solution in which I needed to brand an assembly for a third-party client. This resulted in a class structure as follows:

```
Project1
  References
    MyBrandedAssembly.dll (namespace: MyAssembly)
Project2
  References
    Project1
```

When MsBuild built `Project1`, it could resolve the `MyAssembly` namespace to `MyBrandedAssembly.dll`:

```
Primary reference "MyAssembly".
  Resolved file path is "SolutionPath\Binaries\MyBrandedAssembly.dll".
  Reference found at search path location "{HintPathFromItem}".
```

But when building `Project2`, it could not resolve the second-order reference:

```
Dependency "MyAssembly".
  Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "MyAssembly". 
   Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your  
   code, you may get compilation errors.
    For SearchPath "SolutionPath\Project1\bin\Debug".
    Considered "SolutionPath\Project1\bin\Debug\MyAssembly", but it didn't exist.
```

Why not? And how can I force it to?

Comment: Can you add a reference to MyBrandedAssembly.dll in Project2?

Comment: I could, but is there a more "automatic" way?

Comment: This thread has an alternate solution that could work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dlls-if-using-project-dependencies-in-solution?rq=1

Comment: @SteveWong: Are you thinking of the top solution? That requires both a reference *and* code; it's even less automatic

Comment: as I understood the accepted answer, you have 2 options: 1) add a reference to the dependent assembly (in Project2) OR 2) reference a type of the dependent assembly from your Project1 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a pre-build event to your project csproj file to copy the dlls from the Project 1 output bin folder to the Project 2 bin folder. This will allow the assembly to be found by the assembly resolver.

Add this to your project2.csproj

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Configuration)\MyBrandedAssembly.dll" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)..\<Project1>\bin\$(Configuration)\MyBrandedAssembly.dll" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Configuration)\" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Also if you have a list of dlls you need to copy you can create an item group and reference that in the SourceFiles. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx for additional parameters and an example using a list of files