# Why must an assembly be referenced twice?

Tags: c#, .net

**Question**

It seems to me that any time I make a class library, all of its dependencies should just come with it. In other words, I would expect to just reference a .dll and go. After all, the .dll I reference builds just fine on its own.

Is this not the case? I reference all of a dependency's dependencies, in order to use it?

Looking forward to being enlightened about this.

**Issue**

To illustrate, here's an example.

- `ClassLibrary1` is a class library project, with one public class:
  `Class1`.
- `ClassLibrary2` is another class library, in the same solution, with
  one public class: `Class1`.

  These two classes exist in their own namespaces.

  However, `ClassLibrary2` references `ClassLibrary1`, and `ClassLibrary2.Class1` inherits from `ClassLibrary1.Class1`.
- `ConsoleApplication1` is a console app, in the same solution, that references *only* `ClassLibrary2`.

Up to this point, everything builds. Everything is the same framework.

However, when I attempt to initiate `ClassLibrary2.Class1`, I get a build error:

> Error 1   The type 'ClassLibrary1.Class1' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. ...\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  12  4   ConsoleApplication1

**Code Snippets**

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1() { }
    }
}
```

...

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1 : ClassLibrary1.Class1
    {
        public Class1() : base() { }
    }
}
```

...

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using ClassLibrary2;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // error mentioned previously in post is on following line
            var a = new Class1();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should'n, but ClassLibrary1.dll must be accessible.

Comment: I think it's just how C# and .NET work. `ClassLibrary1` is a direct dependency of `ClassLibrary2` and `ClassLibrary2` is a direct dependency of `ConsoleApplication1`, so `ClassLibrary1` is an indirect dependency of `ConsoleApplication1`. The compiler needs to know that all of the dependencies are available for a particular project before that project is built.

Comment: Exactly, you have to add all (direct or indirect) used libraries to your application. Btw. it is not a good idea to use the same name for classes one derived from the other.

Comment: Do you need reference `ClassLibrary1` in case where `ClassLibrary2` use `ClassLibrary1.Class1` internally?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis if all dependencies are in the same solution, this still holds true?

Comment: The fact that they are in the same solution wouldn't matter. In VS, project level is more important. Each project has its own dependencies and then at build time, the compiler will traverse the dependency tree and copy all the dependencies it needs to the output folder. If one project references another project in VS, all you're really doing is pointing to the location of the built .dll.

Comment: There are quite a lot of questions about this already. For example:http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132243/5311735

Comment: @coolboyjules thanks for clarification. I think if you posted with a reference to some documentation on this process it would qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to formulate an answer here. It helps to look at dependencies on the project level in VS and hopefully it will be more clear.

Suppose you have two projects, `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` in a solution. Both projects reference an assembly `Important.dll`. By reference here, I am referring to if you right click -> Add 'Reference' in a VS project. Suppose also, that `ProjectA` references `ProjectB` in our solution in VS. By this I mean, right click -> 'Add Reference' -> 'Solution' -> Pick `Project B`

What is actually going on? Remember, all a VS reference is a way to help the compiler find the .dll. At build time (compiling), VS will go through all the projects in the solution that are required to be built (you can see this in the Configuration Manager). It will notice that both `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` are set to build. Then it will look at all its direct dependencies in the references section by traversing the dependency tree. For all the VS references that are set to 'Copy local' (true by default), they will be sent to the build folder. So `Important.dll` will go to the build folder.. you probably knew that.

But `ProjectA` references `ProjectB` in VS. When you have a project that references another project in a solution, all you're really doing is pointing to the built .dll of that project... in this case `ProjectB.dll`. It's no different from antoher .dll. You can see this if you look at the references section under 'Path' in `ProjectA`... it'll be something like `C:\users\jdwqdwqd\vs\ProjectB\ProjectB\bin\x64\ProjectB.dll`. So this will be copied to the output folder as well.

I guess one might ask 'Won't `Important.dll` be copied twice along with `ProjectB.dll?`. VS gives you a lot of help here and will pick the correct .dll to copy.

Hope this helps.

Some more information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's just the way C# works.  The inheritance rules seem to be skewed.  I'm working on a massive project at work, and I can use class libraries and namespaces across multiple files, but I have to reference them every time, regardless of inheritance.  It's weird and annoying.  Maybe they'll fix that soon.

Comment: Sounds like a very non-technical explanation to me. After all, you can explain _everything_ with "It's just the way xyz works".

Comment: this is really a comment

Comment: You could explain just about everything that way.  Let me know when you have a more technical answer, and I'll make sure to critique it.