# Nuget - LNK2019 when using one of my project that links to a nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, linker-errors, lnk2019

Ok my problem is simple, but i can't figured it out.

In a single solution I have a project (Application exe) that references another one (lib). This lib references a nuget package, for instance, CxImage.

**.targets**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>"$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)include";%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <!-- patch -->
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>"$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)include\cximage";%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="$(Configuration.ToLower().StartsWith('release')) And '$(Platform.ToLower())'=='x64'">
    <Lib>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>"$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)lib\x64";%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Lib>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>CxImage.lib;jpeg.lib;png.lib;tiff.lib;zlib.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>"$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)lib\x64";%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="$(Configuration.ToLower().StartsWith('debug')) And '$(Platform.ToLower())'=='x64'">
    <Lib>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>"$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)lib\x64";%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Lib>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>CxImage_d.lib;jpeg_d.lib;png_d.lib;tiff_d.lib;zlib_d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>"$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)lib\x64";%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="$(Configuration.ToLower().StartsWith('release')) And '$(Platform.ToLower())'=='win32'">
    <Lib>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>"$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)lib\x86";%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Lib>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>CxImage.lib;jpeg.lib;png.lib;tiff.lib;zlib.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>"$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)lib\x86";%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="$(Configuration.ToLower().StartsWith('debug')) And '$(Platform.ToLower())'=='win32'">
    <Lib>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>"$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)lib\x86";%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Lib>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>CxImage_d.lib;jpeg_d.lib;png_d.lib;tiff_d.lib;zlib_d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>"$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)lib\x86";%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

When building the other project that references this lib, it results in a LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CxImage::CxImage(unsigned int)" (??0CxImage@@QAE@I@Z) referenced in function

Means that it cannot find lib file of cxImage.

I found a way to fix the problem but I don't think it's right.
In the properties of the lib used in other apps, in *Librarian > General > Additionnal Dependencies*, I added cxImage lib. I though that the first idea behind nuget package was to avoid this kind of thing so...

**  it's not related to cxImage, the problem occurs in any other case. I just mentioned this one for instance

Any idea ?? ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Nuget - LNK2019 when using one of my project that links to a nuget package

You should also add the nuget package `CxImage` to the reference project.

The project references the `lib` and the `lib` references the nuget package `CxImage`, so the project not reference the nuget package `CxImage` directly, Visual Studio/MSBuild tries to be smart and only bring references `lib` over into project rather than add nuget package `CxImage` to project. **Because Visual Studio/MSBuild does not know the indirectly reference `CxImage` whether is required by the project or not**. So Visual Studio/MSBuild does not add the nuget package to the reference project to avoid reference pollution the project. You can refer to the [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dll-files-if-using-project-dependencies-in-sol) for detailed info.

In this case, you will get that error "*cannot find lib file of cxImage*". To resolve this issue, you should also add the nuget package `CxImage` to the reference project, so that the projest reference the nuget package `CxImage` directly.