# How to reference dll from another project?

Tags: wpf, xaml, dll

How do I reference the FontAwesome.WPF dll from the OtherProject in the Test project.

In the OtherProject I reference it like this:

```
xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"
```

I know how to reference the project itself:

```
xmlns:fa="clr-namespace:OtherProject;assembly=OtherProject"
```

But I think the namespace should change, however I don't know to what and where to find it?

[image]

This is the FontAwesome.WPF in the object browser:

[image]

I don't know how the first reference would relate to this or might help me or if this is even possible?

So what I want is calling this:

```
<fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Flag" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Without installing the NuGet package in the Test project.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the following accepted answer.

[MSBuild doesn't copy references (DLL files) if using project dependencies in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dll-files-if-using-project-dependencies-in-sol)

In short, you have two options:

- Install the NuGet package in the test project as well.
- Add some *code* (not only XAML markup) in the `OtherProject` that references a type in the `FontAwesome` assembly.

Then the assembly should be copied to the test project's output directory.