# C# Project dependencies without reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, dependencies, csproj

I have a solution with a multiple projects.

Let's say I have projects :

- **P1**
- **P2** with a reference to **P1**
- **P3**
- **P4** with a reference to **P1** and **P3** a dependency to a nugget package **N1**

**P2** is my startup project.

I would like to configure **P2** with a dependency to **P4** so **P4** will be build and **P4** and the dependencies pushed to the bin folder of **P2** but I don't want **P2**'s dll to have a .net reference to **P4**

I partially managed to do that with a specific project reference in the csproj :

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\P4\P4.csproj">
  <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
  <OutputItemType>Content</OutputItemType>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <Targets>Build;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup</Targets>
</ProjectReference>
```

But this solution does only add **P4** and not the dependencies (**P3** and **N1**)

Does anyone knows how to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: and why cannot you put all references into P2?

Comment: I don't want to. Depending on how and where P2 will be deployed, not all the P4-like projects will be deployed.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone knows how to do that?

This is default behavior for **indirect dependencies**.

If project **P4** doesn't actually contain any code that explicitly uses reference project **P3** and nuget package **N1**, VS/MSBuild doesn't detect that **P3**, **N1** is required by **P2**, so MSBuild does not think its necessary to copy the **P3**, **N1** to the output folder of **P2**. That is the reason why only add **P4** and not the dependencies (**P3** and **N1**) into **P2**'s bin directory.

To resolve this issue, you can directly reference **P3**, **N1** to project **P2** or add a copy command line in the **P2**`s build event to copy those dll to the bin folder.

Besides, you can also add dummy code to a file in project P2 that uses project reference **P3**, **N1**.

See [MSBuild doesn't copy references (DLL files) if using project dependencies in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dll-files-if-using-project-dependencies-in-sol) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. **P4** use directly **P3** and **N1**. But effectively, **P2** does not use **P4** or **P3** or **N1**

Comment: @luke77, what do you mean "`I would like to configure P2 with a dependency to P4`"? Do you want P2 reference P4 or P4 reference P2? Need confirm.

Comment: Sorry, by dependency I mean a build dependency. If I build P2, I want also P4 to be built and P4, P3, N1 "paste" to P2's bin.

Comment: @luke77, if you want `If I build P2, I want also P4 to be built`, why do not you set P2 reference P4? You do not want set that? If yes, you can add a custom task in the P2 to build P4 before build P2 and copy P3, N1 to P2`s bin folder.

Comment: @luke77, what about this issue now? Have you resolve it? If not,  Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: hi, sorry for my late answer. 

I could not find a way to do it as I would like.

I thinking about making a real reference on P4 from P2 to automatically include what is required but with conditionnal parameters passed during the build to include or not P4 (depending on the target I'm building for)

Comment: @luke77, Thanks for your response, it would be hard to achieve the function as you like, but like our previous discussion, using certain workaround instead of the it would be a path for this question. Have a nice day:)

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT: You mentioned adding a custom task to build P4 and copy P3, N1 to P2`s bin folder. Would you please be so kind to point me to an example/snippet/discussion on the topic?