# devenv building solution doesn't copy third party dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, compilation

I have a solution with two projects:

1. **Project_X** (class library) with reference to **log4net**(copy local = true)
2. **asp.net website** with reference to **Project_X**

**Project_X** has code using **log4net**, in particular **Log:ILog** interface implementation. 
Website has some code using Log from **Project_X**.  When i build project in studio (VS 2015) i get successful build with log4net.dll in Web Site directory.
When i build solution using **devenv.com** in command line(*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>devenv.com "{path}{name}.sln" /rebuild*), log4net is not copied. 
Why **log4net** is not copied to **Asp.net WebSite** when i build solution using **devenv** ?

PS: i spent a few days looking for answer, found a few post related to this question, but until now haven't found answer.

Comment: @mtv copyLocal set to true , tried add reference directly , same.

Comment: @zrt read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dll-files-if-using-project-dependencies-in-sol

Comment: @giri-webdev yeah, i checked this link a few times, but for me still doesn't work . vs2015

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add reference to log4net directly in to website project. Command line may not check the hierarchy for references while compiling.

And yes. Don;t forget to set Copy Local to true on that reference.