# Do .NET Core projects have MSBuild bug where DLL references from project dependencies are not copied into bin?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild

For .NET Framework projects, MSBuild has (IMO a bug) an issue where, sometimes, DLL references in project dependencies are not copied to the bin folder.  Here's a pretty full discussion of the issue: 
[MSBuild doesn't copy references (DLL files) if using project dependencies in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dll-files-if-using-project-dependencies-in-sol)

Is this also the case in .NET Core projects?

Comment: You might consult Microsoft directly https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues

Comment: @LexLi - thanks!  I cross-posted over there: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/4156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this will be released with netcoreapp3.0

See here: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/4156