# "Copy Local" does not copy assemblies to output directory

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have an assembly X that is referencing `System.Interactive` and `System.Reactive` from a lib folder.
Then I have assembly Y that is referencing X.

In X for both, `System.Interactive` and `System.Reactive`, 'Copy Local' is set to true.
In Y for X 'Copy Local' is set to true.
`System.Reactive` and `System.Interactive` are not in the GAC.

When I build Y, `System.Interactive` and `System.Reactive` are not copied to the output directory. Why?

Answer (score 4):

Y does not inherit "copy local" options from X. If you want System.Interactive and System.Reactive to be deployed with Y, then reference them both from Y, and in Y mark them as "Copy Local = true".

Answer (score 3):

This seems to fix it: [How does visual studio determine what to copy to the output directory with multi-project solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353617/how-does-visual-studio-determine-what-to-copy-to-the-output-directory-with-multi/2828191#2828191)

I manually added True in .csproj to the reference to X in project Y and the assemblies were copied to the output directory.

Answer (score 3):

1. add reference
2. add link

Not any need to add reference into main project.
100% work and copy dlls to bin folder.

```
 <Reference Include="NM86">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\NM86.dll</HintPath>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
   <Content Include="..\..\..\NM86.dll">
      <Link>NM86.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    </Content>
```