# Do client applications still need to reference Log4Net if using Castle LoggingFacility?

Tags: castle-windsor, castle

The reason I ask this is if the log4net.dll is not in the GAC and not in the current Executing Assembly directory, castle Logging facility will not find it.

I have built a class library that is going to be used by multiple client applications to do logging using Castle and Windsor, I have noticed that I don't need a reference to the log4net.dll in my class library at all, it just needs to be able to see the dll at runtime.

So I am just wondering where the reference should truly be because if I put in my class library it is not copied over to clients even though copy local is true, I think because it actually is never used directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to provide log4net.dll to get Castle logging facility to work (assuming you have configured the logging facility to use log4net).  You are correct that you no longer need to reference log4net directly in your projects, because you will now be using Castle.Core's ILogger interface to actually write log messages.  Your application still depends on log4net, albeit indirectly.

Visual studio normally handles these kinds of "indirect" references (A depends on B depends on C) properly (it copies C over to A's output directory).  However, it does *not* copy the indirect reference (it does not copy C to A's output directory) when C is in the GAC on the machine performing the build.

My guess is that you have log4net.dll GAC'd on your development machine.

To resolve this, you either need to remove log4net.dll from your GAC (and from the GAC on any machine where you'll be building the app), or you must *explicitly* reference log4net.dll in your top-level executable (project A in the example above) *and* set "copy local" to true.  This forces the compiler to copy the dll to the output directory.

This issue was also discussed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353617/)

Comment: log4net.dll is not in the GAC, so I am not sure why C is not copied to A when I have log4net referenced in my class library that uses Castle Windsor (B) and in A I reference B.

Comment: Doh, my fault it is copying it over now, I think I origninaly did not have the reference to log4net.dll in (B).

Comment: Sigh I don't know what the issue is I tried it again by cleaning solution A and Solution B and rebuilding B than A and C is not copied over, frustrating.

Comment: The link you posted there is a reply that when using Dependency Injection and the dll is not used in code Copy Local will be ignored, Is that the case here? I notice that not only is Log4net.dll not copied to A's ouput directory niethier is Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.dll.

Comment: Are you using xml configuration?  If you have a reference to Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.dll somewhere (to register it via the programatic API, for example), I'd expect that assembly, and log4net, to get copied around.  If you're using xml, and therefore have no "real" references anywhere, your only recourse is to explicitly reference (and copy local) those guys in your exe project.

Comment: Nope I am not using xml configuration. Client Application (A) references my class library (B) that has references to both log4net and Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.dll (C's), as well as the other castle dll's. log4net.dll and Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.dll are not copied to the output directory of the client application.

Comment: Do you actually have code in (B) that uses Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.dll?  Like a custom IWindsorInstaller?  If the compiler detects that there is no code using a reference, it won't copy that reference downstream (to A).

Comment: Yes, I have a LoggingInstaller that installs the LoggingFacility, using AddFacility.

Comment: Wow, then I am somewhat at a loss.  I'd have to rig this up myself to see if I can repro -- not sure if I'll have time to do that at work today...

Comment: Yeah I am at a loss too, since neithier of those two dll's are in the GAC.

Comment: Actually the LoggingFacility resides in Castle.Facilities.Logging, so to re-answer your question there is no direct usage in code of Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.dll or Log4Net.dll, which makes me think this is why they are not copied over.

Comment: That would do it.  So you either need to add some code in B that directly uses Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.dll or you need to explicitly reference them in the exe project.

Comment: I think if they were in the GAC that would solve the problem too.

Comment: You'd have to GAC them on any machine that ran your app, then.  You want to find a solution where these two dlls are packaged with your app, and not rely on the GAC.

Comment: I don't see why having a bat or powershell script that installs them to the gac would be a bad thing.

Comment: That kind of thing just adds complexity, IMO.  It's simpler/cleaner to have everything you need to run the application packaged up with the "deployable artifact" -- the folder containing your exe.