# C# missing reference from Debug folder

Tags: c#

I can't resolve the following error:

```
Metadata file '******\bin\Debug\EXAMPLE.dll' could not be found
```

When I wanted to build the solution it is all time calling this error and I tried to find solution for this but nothing helped. For example I tried deleting .vs folder etc. When I click on this error to see this reference and where it is used nothing happens.

I saw this question: [In C# solution, created referenced dll in debug folder, odd situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904229/in-c-sharp-solution-created-referenced-dll-in-debug-folder-odd-situation)

But not more about this situation. Is there any solution or tip?

Comment: This is most likely because there is a compile error in your `EXAMPLE` project, leading to a project that depends on it to fail

Comment: Okay. Thank you. This is the only error I got, but I'll see if I can access to that project too.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple projects in your solution.

Build each project step by step. Do not build all solution to find error.

Later, missing .dll (EXAMPLE project) probably did not build. Please re-build that project and make sure that example.dll is created.

After this step, the project which use example.dll should be re-builded. Also please make sure that the project use example.dll is referenced the correct path. What I mean is that if project A search example.dll in folder B but actually wants to find in folder C, it may not work.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll try to debug it like that as you were right and I have multiple projects in solution.